# ViewModel now working! Return me error does not contain a definition for 'Loadss' and no accessible extension method accepting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

i stuck with this kind of basic problem.
I Create ViewModel to be able to pass to View data from two tables:

Model:

```
  public class InvoiceReportViewModel
    {
        public class CurrencyAndWeatherViewModel
        {
            public IEnumerable<loads> Loadss { get; set; }
            public invoices CurrentInvoice { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
            var loadsss = db.loads.Where(x => x.reportid == inv.reportid).ToList();
            var modeli = new CurrencyAndWeatherViewModel { Loadss = loadsss, CurrentInvoice = inv };
            return View("Invoice", modeli);
```

View:

```
@model app.Models.InvoiceReportViewModel

    <div class="container-fluid">

     @{ foreach (var item in Model.Loadss)
         {

         }
```

Always tell me:

```
 Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'InvoiceReportViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'Loadss' and no accessible extension method 'Loadss' accepting a first argument of type 'InvoiceReportViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    38_Views_Accounting_Invoice.cshtml  C:\Users\zhovn\source\repos\BKN\app\Views\Accounting\Invoice.cshtml 10  Active
```

Comment: you are returning model CurrencyAndWeatherViewModel  while the view accept model InvoiceReportViewMode, the Loadss defined in the CurrencyAndWeatherViewModel  not in the InvoiceReportViewMode

Comment: Your class wich contains Loadss is nested in InvoiceReportViewModel.Consequently, they are not a part of your ViewModel class InvoiceReportViewModel. Put your properties inside InvoiceReportViewMode directly and it should works

Answer (score 1):

You should use same `Type` for model in view:

```
@model app.Models.CurrencyAndWeatherViewModel
<div class="container-fluid">
    @{
        foreach (var item in Model.Loadss)
        {
        }
    }
</div>
```